# Running copy command in SConstruct doesn't effect

Tags: linux, scons

When I want to copy file in Linux platform, with this SConstruct file:

```
Command('/lib64/'+ tbbLibNames[i] , tbb_dylibs + '/' + tbbLibNames[i], Copy("$TARGET", "$SOURCE"))
```

it doesn't take effect. But when I move the command to the SConscript, it will take effect.

Please tell me why.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail?  There's no difference what file the instruction appears in, but it does make a difference what the local context is, and we can't see that.  Does "doesn't take effect" mean the Command is not executed at all, or doesn't seem to have the right values, or ... ?

Comment: @MatsWichmann the Command is not exectuted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your target is in `/lib64/` and that is not under (a subdirectory) the current directory (most likely) when you run scons, it is not built by default.

The default target if you do not specify a target on the scons command line is `.`

So try the following:
`scons /lib64`

That should work.

Additionally if you want that target to to be built by default (when you don't explicitly specify targets on the command line (like above), you can use the following

```
targets = Command('/lib64/'+ tbbLibNames[i] , tbb_dylibs + '/' + tbbLibNames[i], Copy("$TARGET", "$SOURCE"))
Default(targets)
```

I'd guess based on where the targets are being copied that you might want to have a target named something like `install`

If so you can do the following

```
targets = Command('/lib64/'+ tbbLibNames[i] , tbb_dylibs + '/' + tbbLibNames[i], Copy("$TARGET", "$SOURCE"))
Alias('install',targets)
```

Then you'd cause scons to copy the files there via
`scons install`

Another option would be to just add the Copy() above as a Post Action to whatever builds those tbbLibNames.. via `AddPostAction()`

See: https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#f-AddPostAction